# Install kompozer on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, kompozer

I'm new (again) to ubuntu. I tried a few years ago and then never actually used it again. Now I'm trying again. I use dreamweaver on Windows because it has a nice side by side view of the code and the WYSIWYG, and can also manage a project. I remembered Kompozer being able to do these things as well, so tried installing it.
I'm aware that Kompozer has stopped and is no longer being maintained, but I couldn't find any alternative that has these two options so started to try anyway.
Following the instructions on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallKompozer I managed to get it working, but when I perform a software update it gets removed again. I also get the 'Error Broken count >0' notification, and cannot update until I remove kompozer again.

While installation the only error I get is that libidl0 is not installed. When I try to install it, I get the message that it has been replaced by libidl-2-0:i386 libidl-2-0. I've installed these two packages but it doesn't solve the problem.

Any help for this newbie?

Comment: I don't have a direct answer for you, but I want to let you know about http://bluegriffon.org/ , a very similar program that is available for Ubuntu and still being updated.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I had a look at bluegriffon, but it doesn't have a split view, and cannot manage a project.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the problematic command as well as its *full verbatim* output. To capture the output you can either 1) select, copy & paste the terminal content or 2) [save it to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (>100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is still possible to do, although a little convoluted:

1. The package `libidl0` is no longer present in Xenial; you can still find it in Trusty.  You therefore have to install it manually.  Go to http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libidl0 and download the file for your architecture (i. e. `amd64` for 64 bit systems) and install it.
2. Then you can follow the [original instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallKompozer) minus the `libidl0` package installation.

---

The installation can be abridged to just two commands once you have the three Deb package files in the current working directory:

```
sudo dpkg -i libidl0_*.deb kompozer_*.deb kompozer-data_*.deb
sudo apt install -f
```

The first will likely end in a missing dependencies error which the 2nd command will fix.

Comment: No longer works. lnstallation of libidl0 causes requirement to install libidl-common. Installation of libidl-common causes removal of libidl0!

Comment: On new installation of 18.04, libidl0 problem problem is fixed but now getting  kompozer depends on libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0); however: Package libpango1.0-0 is not installed.
That is fixable as per my Answer in https://askubuntu.com/questions/832913/unable-to-install-kompozer-in-ubuntu-16-04.